# Change header.php of a specific Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, child-theme, headers, network-admin

I wish to change to change the header.php of child theme and add `<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff6600" />` into it.

However when using the editor under 'Network Admin', changes are reflected across all the wordpress multisites.

How can I access change the header.php of a specific multisite, as the editor is not available in the multisite's dashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you're using one theme across multiple blogs inside your network? If that's the case, you could edit the `header.php` to add a bit of php logic into it to check on what blog your header is currently loaded.

To make it work, you'll need to get the ID of a blog you want to apply the change to (check for it in your network admin on a screen that lists all the blogs).

Then edit the `header.php` and add something like this:

```
<?php 
// 6 in my example is the blog ID that I want to apply the change to
if ( 6 === get_current_blog_id() ) {
    echo `<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff6600" />`;
}
?>
```

The other way would be to create a new child theme with a header.php file that has the additional meta tag and activate it only on a particular blog.

Hope that helps!